How to Set Youtube Video Language using Google Youtube API?
I am trying to set Video Language for the video upload using Google's Youtube API. Here is the upload interface look like.

I try to set it up using defaultLanguage snippet, as shown below, but it did not do anything.
Is it possible to set the Video Language to something specific (say French)? Please help.
def initialize_upload(youtube, options):
  tags = None
  if options.keywords:
    tags = options.keywords.split(",")

  body=dict(
    snippet=dict(
      title=options.title,
      description=options.description,
      tags=tags,
      categoryId=options.category
    ),
    status=dict(
      privacyStatus=options.privacyStatus,
      defaultLanguage="en",     # <<<< ====== this did not work
      publishAt=options.publishAt
    )
  )


defaultLanguage="en"

should be inside the "snippet" and not the "status"
so correct snippet:
snippet=dict(
          title=options.title,
          description=options.description,
          tags=tags,
          defaultLanguage="en",
          categoryId=options.category
        )

but it appears it only sets the "title and description" language, and not the "video language", for the last one you need to add: defaultAudioLanguage="en"
Also all the properties are inside the documentation which is here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos?hl=fr#properties
